# python help >> modules gives segmentation fault - how to fix?

Tags: python

Welcome to Python 2.7!  This is the online help utility.
...

```
>> help()

help> modules

Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gobject/constants.py:24: Warning: g_boxed_type_register_static: assertion `g_type_from_name (name) == 0' failed
  import gobject._gobject
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: g_boxed_type_register_static: assertion `g_type_from_name (name) == 0' failed
  from gtk import _gtk

** (python:9642): CRITICAL **: pyg_register_boxed: assertion `boxed_type != 0' failed
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: cannot register existing type `GdkDevice'
  from gtk import _gtk
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: g_type_get_qdata: assertion `node != NULL' failed
  from gtk import _gtk
Segmentation fault
durrantm.../dmWorkflow$
```

Comment: Are you sure there is nothing wrong with the installation of that `gtk ` package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a known problem when using `help` on Python.  It currently has to import modules to inspect their docstrings and this may result in crashes if the modules execute code upon import and call third-party libraries that expect a certain execution context or that may just be buggy. Here's an [open Ubuntu issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/+bug/896836) about this specific case.  There are a number of open issues in the [Python issue tracker](http://bugs.python.org) about similar crashes due to `help` importing.