# How to view all modules instead of help('modules')?

Tags: enthought

Given that help('modules') has been disabled in enthought because of [this python bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223953/python-help-modules-gives-segmentation-fault-how-to-fix), how can one get a list of all the modules they have? I know that enpkg --list shows all the packages installed with Enthought, but is there a way to view ALL packages or modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ipython terminal, if you type "import", then type a space and press the tab key, you will see ipython's best guess at all the modules that you could import. This list might not be complete, because python lets developers [customize the behavior of the import command](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/sys/imports.html#custom-importers). The list will also include internal modules which you should not actually import. If you precede the tab by other characters, these will filter the list to modules beginning with those characters.

Note that most complex packages contain many modules. Looking at the subdirectories in your python site-packages directory, and at the contents of the file site-packages/easy-install.pth is another way to see typically installed 3rd party installed packages.